# Programatically create WMS and specify data sources in QGIS Server from a web app

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, wms, web-mapping, qgis-server

Is it possible to programatically create a WMS and specify data sources in QGIS Server from a custom web app?

Let's say I have a QGIS project being served up by QGIS Server and accessible via a web client (Lizmap or QWC2 for example). Features are stored in PostGIS (or MSSQL or GPKG). Symbols and labels are all set up and looking good:

```
http://localhost/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetCapabilities&MAP=/home/ubuntu/qwc2/proj1.qgs
```

Now suppose I want to create a second WMS that points to a new set of similar PostGIS layers located nearby.  Rather than manually create a second QGIS project with layers renamed and data sources changed:

```
http://localhost/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetCapabilities&MAP=/home/ubuntu/qwc2/proj2.qgs
```

Is there a way to programatically create this new QGIS project (new WMS) from say a custom web app using Python?  The only difference between proj1.qgs and proj2.qgs would be layer names, data sources and the bounding box.  The underlying PostGIS layer schema (geometry, fields) are identical.

I have a QWC2 web map that contains multiple themes (one QGIS project per theme).

My ultimate goal is to create a new theme by specifying a new data source in a custom web app.  The new WMS would then get created automatically.